# How to create a megamenu where not all the text is links, and where layout is more varied than just N columns throughout

Tags: routes

I want to create a mega-menu with the same kind of layout as the table below, where the plant names are links but the classificatory headings are not:

> Ferns
> Bracken
>
>    Conifers
> Fir Yew Pine
> Cypress Cedar
>
>    Dicotelydons  -  (edible)
> Turnip  Beetroot  Grape  Okra
>
>    Dicotelydons  -  (not edible)
> Duckweed    Yarrow    Sundew
> Oxlip            Elm

Although there are mega-menu modules that display multi-column tables, the output I want differs from what I think they can produce. First, my menu may need different numbers of columns in different sections. As far as I can see, existing mega-menu modules can't do that, because they just take a list of links (either from a Drupal menu, or from a sequence of HTML <LI> elements) and divide it into a fixed number of columns.

Second, my menu may need classificatory headings which are not links and which are not aligned with the links under them. As far as I can see, existing mega-menu modules can't do that either, because they take the non-links from the same list as the links.

I was therefore wondering whether there are any modules that allow the user to input an arbitrary chunk of HTML, and then mark certain pieces of text as menu links, for example by surrounding them by brackets analogous to HTML <A>...</A> tags, or by using a WYSIWYG link-insertion tool. In my example, I'd want to do that to all the plant names.

Before asking this question, I examined Giga Menu, Maximenu, Mega Dropdown, Mega Menu, Menu Minipanels, Menu Views, Mucho Menu, OM Maximenu, Superfish, and TB Mega Menu. I don't think any of these do what I want.

From the above, I discarded Gigamenu because it doesn't have a documentation page, and its Drupal-7 download is dev only. Maximenu and OM Maximenu also have no documentation; and one is an update of the other, but it's not clear which the author now intends us to use. Mega Dropdown is an experimental "sandbox" project.

Menu Views doesn't have documentation, apart from some blog postings about it, but it seems to be intended to replace links by views, which isn't what I need.

Mega Menu, TB Mega Menu, Menu Minpanels, and Superfish turn Drupal menus into mega-menus. That doesn't give me the control over layout that I want — at least I don't think it does.

Mucho Menu *might* do what I want, but has no documentation apart from a video, which I can't hear where I am. Also, I'm not sure that it's maintained any more.